# How to extend the H3Event context type in Nuxt 3

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

In the Nuxt 3 documentation, there's an [example](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#server-middleware) that shows using server middleware to annotate requests with additional information via `event.context`:

```
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  event.context.auth = { user: 123 }
})
```

However, there is no example of how to make the corresponding TypeScript typing for this. I'd prefer my `event.context.auth` not to be an `any` type.

The standard TypeScript library type extension method doesn't seem to work correctly here. I tried to make a `shims.d.ts` containing the following:

```
declare module 'h3' {
  interface H3EventContext {
    auth: AuthSession
  }
}
```

However, this breaks the type inference on the `defineEventHandler` function, making all `event` parameters into implicit `any`s. How can I declare my event context type without breaking stuff?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that we can use TypeScript's [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html). As Nuxt uses `h3` module behind the scenes, so we need to extend the `h3` module and add our custom types. We can do something like this:

```
type MyFancyAuthType = {
  user: number
}

declare module 'h3' {
  interface H3EventContext {
    auth: MyFancyAuthType;
    // any other type
  }
}

export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  // Here you will be able to access .auth on context with proper intellisense
  event.context.auth = { user: 123 }
})
```

You may explicitly define this in a separate file for example `shim.d.ts`. If you do so you need to tell TypeScript compiler.

##### `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  ...
  "files": ["shim.d.ts"]
  ...
}
```

Further, you need to make sure you must add `export default {}`. It should be like this:

##### `shim.d.ts`

```
...
declare module 'h3' {
  ...
}

// this is important
export default {};
```

Please note that while this is a widely adopted convention in the TypeScript community, it is not an official language feature documented by TypeScript itself.

Comment: I tried this earlier, but sadly when placed in a separate declaration file, it causes all `defineEventHandler` functions to somehow lose their type inference entirely such that the `event` parameter becomes an `any`. Not sure what's happening there!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your event becomes typed as any. It shouldn't do that and to test this I created an example on StackBlitz that demonstrates that what you did should work as intended.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-uhgayq?file=server%2Fapi%2Ftest.ts

The event is of type H3Event, event.context is H3EventContext and event.context.authenticatedUser is User. The User is defined in /server/user.ts

Maybe I'm missing something, but as you can see it should work fine the way you did it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be giving correct types in your example.